# How to modify a certain object in array of objects that stored in redux state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux, javascript-objects

let's say I've data stored in a redux state like this

```
state = {
records : [
    {id:"1", name:"foo", city:"A"},
    {id:"2", name:"bar", city:"B"},
    {id:"3", name:"abc", city:"C"},
]
}
```

how do I change any attribute of any record dynamically using immutable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
case 'SOMETHING': 
const recordsCopy = {...state.records};
//change recordsCopy ...
const recordToChange = recordsCopy.find(x => x.id === '3')
if(recordToChange) {
   recordToChange.name = 'new name';
}
return {...state, records: [...recordsCopy]}
```

Comment: how do I change the name of record no.3 only?

Comment: I update the answer.

Comment: if there's no id attribute it is possible to change?

Comment: Find logic is up to you and your design. You should find your item first anyway.

Comment: i mean how do i do the same thing with array index instead of id attribute

Comment: Do you mean something like this? const recordToChange = recordsCopy[2]

Comment: yes, exactly like that

Comment: nevermind, I've solve that using state.records.map(record,i) = >{}

Answer (score 1):

let say, you have the `id` (let 2) of record and you want to update `name` (to "pqr")

```
function reducer (state, action){
  const {type, payload}  = action
  switch(type){
  case: "UPDATE": 
       return updateRecord(state, payload.id, payload.newname)
  default: return state;
  }
}

function updateRecord(state, id, newName){
  const newRecords = state.records.map(rec => {
     if(rec.id === id){ return {...rec, name: newname} }
     return rec
   })
  return {...state, records: newRecords}

}
```